# Eliminar elemento completo de un array bajo una condicion

Tags: javascript, nodejs, delete

Tengo un array extraido de un pdf y deseo eliminar todos aquellos elementos que tengan la cadena str vacia,

```
    {
    "meta": {
    "info": {
        "PDFFormatVersion": "1.4",
            "Language": null,
            "EncryptFilterName": null,
            "IsLinearized": false,
            "IsAcroFormPresent": false,
            "IsXFAPresent": false,
            "IsCollectionPresent": false,
            "IsSignaturesPresent": false,
            "Creator": "JasperReports (reporteSemanasCotizadas)",
            "Producer": "iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT",
            "ModDate": "D:20220713094658-05'00'",
            "CreationDate": "D:20220713094658-05'00'"
    },
    "metadata": null
},
    "pages": [
    {
        "pageInfo": {
            "num": 1,
            "scale": 1,
            "rotation": 0,
            "offsetX": 0,
            "offsetY": 0,
            "width": 612,
            "height": 792
        },
        "links": [],
        "content": [
            {
                "x": 225.13,
                "y": 108.78999999999996,
                "str": "Instituto Mexicano del Seguro Social",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 161.7399999999999,
                "height": 10,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 438.82,
                "y": 210.27999999999997,
                "str": "DD",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 8.664,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 460.82800000000003,
                "y": 210.27999999999997,
                "str": "MM",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 9.996,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 484.16800000000006,
                "y": 210.27999999999997,
                "str": "YYYY",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 16.008,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 247.53,
                "y": 282.04,
                "str": "Tu detalle de semanas cotizadas",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 116.94399999999999,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 201.57,
                "y": 141.78999999999996,
                "str": "Constancia de Semanas Cotizadas en el IMSS",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 207.8699999999999,
                "height": 10,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 462.83,
                "y": 245.03999999999996,
                "str": "363",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 13.344000000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 47,
                "y": 226.03999999999996,
                "str": "NSS:",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 18.672,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 47,
                "y": 205.03999999999996,
                "str": "HERNANDEZ HIGUERA CARLOS ABDIEL",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 154.24800000000002,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 70,
                "y": 226.03999999999996,
                "str": "21139682674",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 48.928000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pageInfo": {
            "num": 2,
            "scale": 1,
            "rotation": 0,
            "offsetX": 0,
            "offsetY": 0,
            "width": 612,
            "height": 792
        },
        "links": [],
        "content": [
            {
                "x": 225.13,
                "y": 108.78999999999996,
                "str": "Instituto Mexicano del Seguro Social",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 161.7399999999999,
                "height": 10,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 312,
                "y": 216.95000000000005,
                "str": "17/09/2021",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 196.95000000000005,
                "str": "BAJA CALIFORNIA",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 70.23999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 388,
                "y": 216.95000000000005,
                "str": "Salario Base de Cotización */",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 103.59999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 216.95000000000005,
                "str": "Fecha de alta",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 48.472000000000016,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 232,
                "y": 216.95000000000005,
                "str": "Fecha de baja",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 50.695999999999984,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 216.95000000000005,
                "str": "20/01/2020",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 196.95000000000005,
                "str": "Entidad federativa",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 64.48,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 518.86,
                "y": 216.95000000000005,
                "str": "$ 620.67",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.13600000000005,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 156.95000000000005,
                "str": "Nombre del patrón",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 66.24800000000002,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 156.95000000000005,
                "str": "TCL MOKA MANUFACTURING",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 113.33599999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 176.95000000000005,
                "str": "Registro Patronal",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 61.80000000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 176.95000000000005,
                "str": "A086348210",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 45.368,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 322.26,
                "y": 252.03999999999996,
                "str": "Fecha de movimiento",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 76.47199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 129.6,
                "y": 252.03999999999996,
                "str": "Tipo de movimiento",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 69.79999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 479.32,
                "y": 252.03999999999996,
                "str": "Salario Base",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 45.352,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 272.03999999999996,
                "str": "17/09/2021",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 154.5,
                "y": 272.03999999999996,
                "str": "BAJA",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 20.008000000000003,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 486.43,
                "y": 272.03999999999996,
                "str": "$ 620.67",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.135999999999992,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "pageInfo": {
            "num": 3,
            "scale": 1,
            "rotation": 0,
            "offsetX": 0,
            "offsetY": 0,
            "width": 612,
            "height": 792
        },
        "links": [],
        "content": [
            {
                "x": 225.13,
                "y": 108.78999999999996,
                "str": "Instituto Mexicano del Seguro Social",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 161.7399999999999,
                "height": 10,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 322.26,
                "y": 141.03999999999996,
                "str": "Fecha de movimiento",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 76.47199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 129.6,
                "y": 141.03999999999996,
                "str": "Tipo de movimiento",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 69.79999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 479.32,
                "y": 141.03999999999996,
                "str": "Salario Base",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 45.352,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 161.03999999999996,
                "str": "01/07/2019",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 109.82,
                "y": 161.03999999999996,
                "str": "MODIFICACION DE SALARIO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 109.35199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 486.43,
                "y": 161.03999999999996,
                "str": "$ 325.18",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.135999999999992,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 181.03999999999996,
                "str": "24/06/2019",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 140.5,
                "y": 181.03999999999996,
                "str": "REINGRESO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 48.007999999999996,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 486.43,
                "y": 181.03999999999996,
                "str": "$ 324.74",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.135999999999992,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 42,
                "y": 201.03999999999996,
                "str": "/* Valor del último salario base de cotización diario en pesos.",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 215.64800000000008,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 312,
                "y": 301.95,
                "str": "26/06/2019",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 281.95,
                "str": "BAJA CALIFORNIA",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 70.23999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 388,
                "y": 301.95,
                "str": "Salario Base de Cotización */",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 103.59999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 301.95,
                "str": "Fecha de alta",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 48.472000000000016,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 232,
                "y": 301.95,
                "str": "Fecha de baja",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 50.695999999999984,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 301.95,
                "str": "23/05/2018",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 281.95,
                "str": "Entidad federativa",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 64.48,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 518.86,
                "y": 301.95,
                "str": "$ 324.74",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.13600000000005,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 241.95000000000005,
                "str": "Nombre del patrón",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 66.24800000000002,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 241.95000000000005,
                "str": "NOMINA INTEGRAL DE SOLUCIONES PRODUCTIVAS",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 202.25600000000006,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 261.95000000000005,
                "str": "Registro Patronal",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 61.80000000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 261.95000000000005,
                "str": "Z312983510",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 44.92,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            }
        ]
    },
],
    "filename": "./Employees/123.pdf"
}
```

estoy usando esta funcion y elimina las cadenas pero queda el {} vacio

```
function eliminarVacios(jsonx){
    for (var str in jsonx) {
        if(typeof jsonx[str] == 'string'){
            if(jsonx[str] == ' '||jsonx[str] == ''){
                delete jsonx.str
                delete jsonx.x
                delete jsonx.y
                delete jsonx.dir
                delete jsonx.width
                delete jsonx.height
                delete jsonx.fontName
            }
        } else if (typeof jsonx[str] == 'object') {
            eliminarVacios(jsonx[str])
        }
    }
    return jsonx
}
```

esto me devuelve el array asi:

```
"content": [
                {
                    "x": 225.13,
                    "y": 108.78999999999996,
                    "str": "Instituto Mexicano del Seguro Social",
                    "dir": "ltr",
                    "width": 161.7399999999999,
                    "height": 10,
                    "fontName": "Helvetica"
                },
                {}, // deseo eliminar esto
                {
                    "x": 438.82,
                    "y": 210.27999999999997,
                    "str": "DD",
                    "dir": "ltr",
                    "width": 8.664,
                    "height": 6,
                    "fontName": "Helvetica"
                },
            ]
```

como podria eliminar todo completo?

Comment: Te convendría usar `filter`, haciendo algo así `jsonx.content.filter(e=>e.str.replace(/ +/g,""));` pero parece que la estructura puede ser mas compleja que el ejemplo que pones, o la estructura pude variar, no?.

Comment: Si, toda la estructura es igual, aqui seria solo eliminar el elemento completo si la cadena str = " ", pero no logro hacerlo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la estructura de tu objeto, básicamente necesitas recorrer los arreglos de pages y verificar el content de cada página. Si el objeto de contenido está vacío o tiene el string vacío, elimínalo con splice. Quedaría tu función algo así:

```
function eliminarVacios(jsonx) {
    let pages = jsonx.pages || [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        let content = pages[i].content;
        for (let j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {
            if (content[j].str == "" || content[j].str == null) {
                content.splice(j, 1);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    return jsonx;
}
```

Comment: Hola Jaime, gracias por responder, tu respuesta es correcta pero el problema es que el json es mas amplio, tiene mas niveles, aqui no me deja escribir codigo, asi que respondere en otra respuesta a ver si puedes ayudarme

Comment: @AbdielHernandez conviene que pongas en tu pregunta la estructura completa. Sin ver los datos de entrada es difícil realizar la función que necesitas.

Comment: Wow! quedo excelente, es justo lo que necesitaba, eres un master! por favor si es posible hacerme llegar tu email, me gustaria ponerme en contacto contigo, mi correo es hh.abdiel@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Como sugerí en los comentarios, se podría usar `.filter`:

```js
const jsonx ={"meta":{"info":{"PDFFormatVersion":"1.4"},"metadata":null},"pages":[{"pageInfo":{"num":1},"links":[],"content":[{"str":"21139682674"},{"str":""},{"str":" "},{"str":"  "}]},{"pageInfo":{"num":2},"links":[],"content":[{"str":"$ 620.67"},{"str":""},{"str":" "},{"str":"  "}]},{"pageInfo":{"num":3},"links":[],"content":[{"str":"Z312983510"},{"str":""},{"str":" "},{"str":"  "}]}],"filename":"./Employees/123.pdf"};

jsonx.pages.forEach((p,i,o)=>o[i].content = p.content.filter(e=>e.str.replace(/ +/g,"")));

console.log(jsonx);
```

El objeto de ejemplo lo reduje a la mínima expresión para hacerlo mas ameno.

Answer (score 0):

Deseas eliminar todos los objetos que contengan alguna key con valor ""

```
const res = jsonx.filter((item) => {

const containEmptyStr = (obj) => {
    let res = false;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      if (obj[key] === "") res = true;
    });
    return res;
  };
  return !containEmptyStr(item)
});

console.log(res);
```

Esto te devolverá otro array con todos aquellos objetos que NO contengan alguna key con valor ""

```
let jsonx = [
    {
        "x": 225.13,
        "y": 108.78999999999996,
        "str": "Instituto Mexicano del Seguro Social",
        "dir": "ltr",
        "width": 161.7399999999999,
        "height": 10,
        "fontName": "Helvetica"
    },
   
    {
        "x": 438.82,
        "y": 210.27999999999997,
        "str": "DD",
        "dir": "ltr",
        "width": 8.664,
        "height": 6,
        "fontName": "Helvetica"
    },
]
```

**Editado**
Usando la misma logica, haciendo mas profunda la busqueda y partiendo de que siempre se recibe y se espera el mismo formato

```
const filterObjectWhithEmptyStrs = (array) => {
  const res = array.filter((item) => {
    const containEmptyStr = (obj) => {
      let res = false;
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (obj[key] === "") res = true;
      });
      return res;
    };
    return !containEmptyStr(item);
  });
  return res;
};

const scanPdf = (pdf) => {
  let pages;
  Object.keys(pdf).forEach((key) => {
    if (key === "pages") {
      pages = pdf[key].map((page) => {
        return { ...page, content: filterObjectWhithEmptyStrs(page.content) };
      });
    }
  });

  return { ...pdf, pages };
};
```

Puedes editarlo  [aquí](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hertz-152905?file=/src/index.js)